# Translate jQuery into javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Because jQuery is not working I need to translate the following into straight javascript.  jQuery does not work on this page, I have more than one jQuery installed and I can't find them.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#printFrame').hide();

        $('#print').click(function () {
            $('#printFrame').attr('src', 'print.php?max=' + $('#brSt').val());
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
    <td>Number desk:</td>
    <td><input type="number" id="brSt" value="10"><td>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" id="print" value="Print"><td>
    </tr>
    <iframe id="printFrame"></iframe>
```

Comment: is this the correct html or just a part of it? the td tag is outside the table. your html is not well formed

Comment: Yes this is part :D And html is not formed but work :D

Comment: you can use document.getElementById to get the object if you don't want to use the jquery. ideally i would recommend you to remove the extra jquery lib. if you can't find it then remove the one that u can find and your code should work fine.

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: I would recommend using wingrep if you are on a windows box to search your directories for the extra jquery reference.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking to refactor code and is unlikely to help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var frame = document.getElementById("printFrame");
   var brStValue = document.getElementById('brSt').value;
   frame.style.display = 'none';

   document.getElementById("print").addEventListener("click", function(){
      frame.setAttribute("src",'print.php?max=' + brStValue);
   });
```

Comment: Don't forget to translate `$('#brSt').val()` as well. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the fact that your HTML is a mess you could use:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Number desk:</td>
                <td><input type="number" id="brSt" value="10"><td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" id="print" value="Print" onClick="srcChange();"><td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <iframe id="printFrame" style="display: none;"></iframe> 
    </body>
    <script>
        function srcChange() {
            var max = document.getElementById('brSt').value;
            document.getElementById('printFrame').src ="print.php?max=" + max;
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is exactly right is it?  In the current code, the print frame remains hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete cross browser solution

```
(function(d){
  var frame = d.getElementById('printFrame'),
      brst = d.getElementById('brSt');
  function updateSource(e){
    frame.src = 'print.php?max=' + brst.value;
  }
  frame.style.display = 'none';
  if(d.addEventListener){
      d.getElementById('print').addEventListener('click',updateSource,'false');
    return;
  }
  if(d.attachEvent){
    d.getElementById('print').attachEvent('click',updateSource);
    return;
  }

}(document));
```